# Run Laravel Horizon as a background service

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs, laravel-horizon

My question is what is the **best** and simple way to run the Laravel Horizon based job workers?

My Tech Stack

- Laravel 5.5
- Horizon
- Redis Queues
- Centos

I have gone through the document https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/horizon

How to setup following supervisor as mentioned on the link above
**Supervisor Configuration**

```
[program:horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/horizon.log
```

**Note:** I have my own custom build server with php 7.1 and I later installed Horizon to run my Jobs and maintain the queues.

Any suggestion regarding how to run the Workers or where should I configure above **Supervisor Configuration**?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure you have supervisor installed:

For debian/ubuntu:

```
apt install supervisor
```

centos:

```
easy_install supervisor
```

or

```
yum install supervisor
```

You can also do:

```
systemctl enable supervisord
```

To make sure supervisor runs at startup

---

Now create a new file in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/` named `horizon.conf` and add the above configuration.

Now do:

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
```

To reread the configs

```
sudo supervisorctl update
```

To reload the configs and restart the process

```
sudo supervisorctl start all
```

or

```
sudo supervisorctl start horizon
```

To start horizon

Comment: Note that if you have an `/etc/supervisord.d/` folder instead; the extension should be `.ini`

Comment: This was helpful.  Is the best way to check that it is running to just go to /horizon ?

Comment: @Jordan Yes, you can see an overview of the running instances on the horizon dashboard page